# Riemann-integrable, Lebesgue-integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> > Hello, I have to decide whether
> >     $$
> > \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\, \mathrm dx
> > $$
> >     is (a) Improper Riemann-integrable, or (b) Lebesgue-integrable.

I search for an improper Riemann-integrable majorant for $f(x):=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$, and a non-Riemann-integrable minorant for $f(x)$...

Majorant:

$$
\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\leq \ldots 
$$

But I don't know how to estimate the denominator...

Comment: Hint: $1+x > x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>1$ we have $x^4<1+x^4<2x^4$. Then

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\,x}< \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} < \frac{1}{x} \;\;\mbox{    if } x>1.
$$

Comment: I have for the majorant: $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert}$. But is $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert}\, dx=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\, dx$ convergent?

Comment: No, it is not. $\int_1^M\frac{1}{x}=\ln M \rightarrow \infty$ as $M\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: But I thought - I need a convergent majorant -

Comment: And the minorant converges here??

Comment: $\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$ dx is not convergent. You can't find a majorant convergent.

Comment: So tum sum it up: The idea is here to put the integral between two terms that divergate? And so the middle integral has to divergate too?

Comment: The inequality that matters in this case is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\,x}< \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} $.

Comment: @math12 : You don't divergate, you diverge :D

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\sim \frac1x, \quad x \to \infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} > \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4+x^4}} > \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^4}} = \frac{1}{2x} \text{ for }|x|>1, \text{ and } \int_{|x|>1} \frac{dx}{2x}=\infty.
$$

Comment: Sorry, my comment was just... weird. I'll remove it. I guess I forgot about that $x$ on top. Shit happens.